# Pandas - Using merge_asof function in index

Tags: python, pandas

The code is:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x,'%d %m %Y %H %M')
vento = pd.read_csv('dados_tpm.txt', header=0, delim_whitespace= True, parse_dates = [['Dia', 'Mes', 'Ano', 'Hora','Minuto']], index_col = False, date_parser = dateparse)
vento1 = vento.rename(columns={'Dia_Mes_Ano_Hora_Minuto': 'Data'})
vento0 = vento1.set_index('Data')
vento_time = pd.DataFrame({'Data':pd.date_range(start='2016-07-12 18:00:00',end='2017-02-28 21:00:00',freq='3H')})
vento_time0 = vento_time.set_index('Data')
vento_2 = pd.merge_asof(vento_time0,vento0, on='Index', tolerance=pd.Timedelta("5 minutes")).fillna('NAN')
```

Where `vento0` is something like:

```
Index               Vel Dir
2016-07-12 16:17:00 9.8  13.8
2016-07-12 16:18:00 10.9 1.8
2016-07-12 16:19:00 10.0 11.1
2016-07-12 16:20:00 11.0 11.0
...                 ...  ...
...                 ...  ...
2017-02-28 22:34:00 9.2  13.7
```

And `vento_time0` seems like:

```
Index
2016-07-12 18:00:00
2016-07-12 21:00:00
2016-07-13 00:00:00
2016-07-13 03:00:00
...        ...
...        ...
2017-02-28 21:00:00
```

My data has an one minute interval and it's non regularised. The objective of this is to put it in a 3 hour interval replacing the missing values with the closests data in a range of five minutes. But when `merge_asof` is used, this error appears: `KeyError: 'Index'`. I also tried to use `Data`, the actual name of indexes but get the same error. The expected output will be:

```
Index                 Vel  Dir
2016-07-12 18:00:00   8.0  55
2016-07-12 21:00:00   16.0 67
2016-07-13 00:00:00   NAN  NAN
2016-07-13 03:00:00   19.0 83
...        ...
...        ...
2017-02-28 21:00:00   NAN  NAN
```

Can anyone help? Is there a way to use merge_asof function in the Index?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do something like this:
Use `.sort_values(by = 'Data')` instead `.set_index`

```
vento0 = vento1.sort_values(by = 'Data')
vento_time0 = vento_time.sort_values(by = 'Data')
```

After do that, this should work:

```
vento_2 = pd.merge_asof(vento_time0,vento0, \
                        tolerance=pd.Timedelta("5 minutes")).fillna('NAN')
```

Be sure that your `'NAN'` becomes "not a number" using:

`vento_2.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)`

After use `merge_asof` and convert your `'NAN'` you can set your index.

`vento_2.set_index(['Data'], inplace=True)`

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to `merge_asof()` on indicies, you need to use the following:

```
vento_2 = pd.merge_asof(vento_time0,vento0, left_index = True, right_index = True, tolerance=pd.Timedelta("5 minutes")).fillna('NAN')
```

Docs here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html

Comment: I tried and it gave me the error:                                                                                                       ValueError: right keys must be sorted

Comment: Then just before you `.set_index('Data')` use `.sort_values(by = 'Data')` and you should be good to go.

Comment: You need both sets to be sorted, so make sure they are. And when you `sort_values` note that you need to either have `df = df.sort_values()` or `sort_values(..., inplace = True)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a different form of `asof()`:

```
vento0.asof(vento_time0.index)
```

Comment: I tried this way and it gave me the error:                                                        ValueError: asof requires a sorted index

Comment: @ItaloLopes: And now that you have that error message I'm sure you know what to do next!