# How to interpolate timestamps from two pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two datasets with data from different devices and I would like to graph them together. The problem is one device measures in ms and the other measures in seconds so I am finding it hard to interpolate the timestamps.

Here is an example of the data (They are usually very long csv files):
device 1 (dfz):

```
Time    HR
13:06.4 70
13:07.4 70
13:08.4 70
13:09.4 73
13:10.4 73
13:11.4 75
13:12.4 87
13:13.4 90
13:14.4 92
```

device 2 (dfr):

```
timestamp   hr[1]
1.55E+12    70
1.55E+12    70
1.55E+12    70
1.55E+12    70
1.55E+12    70
1.55E+12    70
1.55E+12    70
1.55E+12    70
1.55E+12    70
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
df = pd.read_csv('insert csv file')
dfz = (df.loc[:, ['Time', 'HR']])
dfz.set_index('Time')
dfz.Time = pd.to_datetime(dfz.Time).dt.time


df_1 = pd.read_csv('insert csv file', dtype={"timestamp": float, "hr[1]": int})
dfr = (df_1.loc[:, ['timestamp', 'hr[1]']])
dfr.set_index('timestamp')

# Change timestamp to normal timestamp

dfr['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(dfr['timestamp'], unit='ms') - timedelta(hours=8)
dfr['timestamp'] = pd.Series([val.time() for val in dfr['timestamp']])
```

I am able to plot each dataset separately but I would like to combine both so that it creates a dataframe that uses `Time` from the dfz database as the index and plots both `HR` and `hr[1]` on the same graph.

I tried using `pd.merge_asof` but I keep getting `'NoneType' object is not callable` error messages.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: do you find what you need in this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43978970/pandas-using-merge-asof-function-in-index btw, what kind of time do you expect to get out of the number `1.55e12`

Comment: Im trying to get the time formatted by hours, minutes and seconds.f without the date

Comment: I think I've figured out a way to do this but I was wondering if theres any way to remove the milliseconds from the end of both timestamps? For example, this is one of the numbers I am getting in my Time column: `07:59:57.426000`. How can I change this to: `07:59:57`?

Comment: well done, for the formating thing, this should do it for you. `ts = pd.to_datetime('07:59:57.426000')` can be cut with `ts.floor('s')` to output `Timestamp('2019-02-28 07:59:57')`. this does not actually change `dtype` from the internal [ns], so it's basically truncating and not presenting parts of seconds.